# Make set keep order of a tuple

Tags: python, data-structures, set, tuples

In the code below, how can I use keep using `set` to have unique values, but also make `set` keep the order of how the filters are typed in?

```
>>> filters = ('f1', 'f2')
>>> set((*filters, 'f3'))
{'f1', 'f3', 'f2'} # expected: {'f1', 'f2', 'f3'}
```

Comment: In python, dict keep insertion order, so you could use a dict, storing the keys and ignoring the values.

Comment: Sets are inherently unordered. Use a dict, list or tuple if you need to preserve the order. Without knowing what you're planning on using the set for, it's hard to recommend a specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since python3.6/3.7, `dict` are ordered and retain their insertion order.

So, instead of a `set`, you can use a `dict`. Use the keys to store your items, and ignore the values.

```py
>>> filters = ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
>>> d = dict.fromkeys((*filters, 'fifth'))
>>> d
{'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None, 'fourth': None, 'fifth': None}
>>> tuple(d)
('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth')
>>> [*d]
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

Alternative syntax using `zip_longest`:

```py
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> filters = ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
>>> d = dict((*zip_longest(filters, ()), ('fifth', None)))
>>> d
{'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None, 'fourth': None, 'fifth': None}
```

Alternative syntax using a generator expression:

```py
>>> filters = ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
>>> d = dict((*((f,()) for f in filters), ('fifth',())))
>>> d
{'first': (), 'second': (), 'third': (), 'fourth': (), 'fifth': ()}
```

Answer (score 1):

as stated by others in the comment and answer by @Stef, `dictionary` is the way to go:

```
filters = ('f1', 'f2','f3','f4')

list(dict.fromkeys((*filters, 'f5'))  # this will generate only unique as keys are unique and preseve the order as well

#output
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5']
```